# Can I open an executable file from a local webpage using Chromium?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am creating a project to simplify my computer. I have Windows 7, and I am using the Chromium web browser in kiosk mode.

I want to be able to open a program, lets say iTunes or MS Word, from my little kiosk. The html page is local, just sitting in a folder in my documents with all the other stuff I already have. VBscripts will not work.

Any ideas on how or if this will work?

Comment: And shortcuts in a folder using Windows File Explorer are inadequate?

Comment: You can't launch executables from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Write an npapi plugin which exposes a method to JavaScript which takes its arguments and passes them to the Win32 ShellExecute function. You can bundle the plugin as a Chrome Extension, and set it up to only enable the plugin on your kiosk page.

With a bit of googling, you'll probably be able to find someone who has written a plugin like this before, or you could write your own.